# Как передать в метод класса два экземпляра другого класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, объекты, методы

Господа есть код:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, name_player):
        self.hp = hp
        self.name = name_player


knight = Person(2500, 'Рыцарь')
hunter = Person(2000, 'Охотник')


class TheBattle:
    def damage_by_turns(self, player1, player2):
        print('У ', player1.name, ' ', player1.hp, ' жизней.')  
        print('У ', player2.name, ' ', player2.hp, ' жизней.')

TheBattle.damage_by_turns(hunter, knight)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    TheBattle.damage_by_turns(hunter, knight)
TypeError: damage_by_turns() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player2'
```

Т.е. я не передаю в метод объект рыцарь.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поправить?

Comment: Ну, допустим, так ``TheBattle.damage_by_turns(0, hunter, knight)``. Но это неправильно. Нужно создавать объект класса и работать с ним,а не с самими классом, тогда описаная проблема не возникнте.

Comment: Работает! Благодарю. Т.е. отправлять 0 в self безопасно?

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно делать так:

```
mochilovo = TheBattle() # создаем объект класса TheBattle
mochilovo.damage_by_turns(hunter, knight) # вызываем метод класса у объекта
```

Или использовать статический метод:

```
class TheBattle:
    @staticmethod
    def damage_by_turns(player1, player2): # <- без self!
        print('У ', player1.name, ' ', player1.hp, ' жизней.')  
        print('У ', player2.name, ' ', player2.hp, ' жизней.')

TheBattle.damage_by_turns(hunter, knight)
```

Comment: а в питоне нет статических методов?

Comment: Кстати, да. Есть. Щас добавлю.